# i wanted to ask about my training model which i have trained so far i,e is it tending toward accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am new to deep learning and want to know about epoch accuracy regarding tensorboard. I have trained a deep learning model with 400 images each about 960x1280 pixels and I have visualize it on tensorboard. Can anyone help me by telling me that what is meant by epoch accuracy and in my case is it good enough in the picture or what else should I do to match the training and validation accuracy?

The picture is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **title** `epoch_acc` depends on your code.

If you use any predefined model(for example, [keras ResNet50](https://keras.io/applications/) or ready-made model from github) then the **epoch_acc** title will be mentioned somewhere in the code.

In your description no source code is provided. Also, it is not clear which tensorflow api(*tensorflow core* or *keras backed tensorflow*) you are using. It is little difficult to tell the meaning of `epoch_acc`.

Here `epoch_acc` might be ***total accuracy*** with respect to the incremental epoch number. I mean, *Y* axis is for **accuracy** and *X* axis for simple **epoch count** *(how many times you are repeating your entire train dataset.)*

However, please let me give an example what I am telling, please look at this code.

The accuracy metrics *title* will be `softmax_out_acc` and `ring_loss_acc` 
if I use -

```py
model.compile(loss = {'softmax_out' : 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                     'ring_loss' : identity_loss},
               metrics = ['accuracy'], 
               ... )
```

```
32/32 [==============================] - 116s 4s/step - loss: 3.1720 - softmax_out_loss: 0.8834 - ring_loss_loss: 22.8862 - softmax_out_acc: 0.5391 - ring_loss_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.1074 - val_softmax_out_loss: 0.9071 - val_ring_loss_loss: 22.0037 - val_softmax_out_acc: 0.4590 - val_ring_loss_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Or, if you use `cross_entropy` *string* in `tf.summary.scalar` of tensorboard writer [like this:](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard)

```py
with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
  with tf.name_scope('total'):
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=y_, logits=y)
tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', cross_entropy)
```

The output will look like this

[image]

**so, there is nothing well defined `epoch_acc` in deep learning, or `epoch_acc` is not a standards metrics, it entirely depends on your code.**

Answer (score 0):

While [Uzzal Podder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57720035/4072504) is correct, I think it is likely that in your code the **epoch _acc** is representing the accuracy of the model after completing a full epoch of training.

An **epoch** usually represents a full iteration over the training dataset. Therefore, for your dataset, it would mean a full training cycle over the 400 images.

If this assumption is correct, the **epoch_acc** would reflect your training accuracy. To get a testing accuracy, you would want to use the trained model to evaluate a [holdout set of data](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6).

The methodologies to close the gap between training and testing accuracies for CNNs is something that has been answered a number of times on this site and I would recommend looking into those answers first.